# vuejs + drf - unable to get data from drf api in vuejs using http/axios

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, vuejs2

[Image of vuejs folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLJ0O.png)

Unable to get data in Vue js from drf api using http / axios ? I am not getting any error also

App.vue:

```
    <template>
  <div id="app">

    <div id="show-blogs">
        <h1>Mgmt View's</h1>
        {{ info }}
    </div>
    <ul v-if="errors && errors.length">
      <li v-for="error of errors">
        {{error.message}}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data () {
      return {
        info: ""
      }
    },
  created() {

axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/management/api/list/').then(response=> {
          this.info = response.data
    })
    .catch(e => {
      this.errors.push(e)
    })
    }
  }
</script>
```

Here I provide the code of App.vue, rest all file I have not change anything

Comment: Could you please post your code. A screenshot of directory is unlikely going to be helpful.

Comment: attached the code + image

Comment: with postman I am able to get the data